# The set of all sigmoid functions with slope $1$ at the origin and $\lim\limits_{x→+∞}f(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading about [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and especially the ones with slope $1$ at the the origin.

For some data I think a sigmoid function with slope $1$ at the origin and upper bound $1$ may be an exact fit. Now I want to try to loop through the set of sigmoid functions.

However I need to know all possible sigmoid functions with slope $1$ at the origin and upper bound $1$, and so far I have just seen a few examples that happen to suffice. Are there more functions with these properties?

In short, is it possible to construct a set that contains all S-shaped functions that have slope $1$ at the origin and an upper bound of $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$For any sigmoid function $f$, if $f'$ is discontinuous at some point $x_0$, then Darboux's theorem implies that at least one of the left limit and right limit of $f'$ at $x_0$ does not exist (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function)). Thus the set of sigmoid functions below are sufficient for practical use.

Define $\mathscr{S}$ to be the set of all functions\begin{align*}
f:&& \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&& x &\longmapsto \int_0^x g(t) \,\d t
\end{align*}
where $g \in C(\mathbb{R}),$ $0 \leqslant g \leqslant 1,$ $g(0) = 1,$ $\displaystyle \int_{-∞}^0 g(t) \,\d t < + ∞$, $\displaystyle \int_0^∞ g(t) \,\d t = 1$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$. For any $f \in \mathscr{S}$, $f' = g$ implies $f$ being increasing and $0 \leqslant f' \leqslant 1$, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$, and$$
\lim_{x → +∞} f(x) = \int_0^∞ g(t) \,\d t = 1,\\
|f(x)| \leqslant \int_{-∞}^∞ g(t) \,\d t < +∞. \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
thus $f$ satisfies the given conditions.

---

Now define $\mathscr{T}$ to be the set of all functions $h: \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ satisfiying:

1. $h \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$,

   $h(x) = x\ (\forall x \leqslant 0)$, $h(x) → +∞\ (x → +∞)$,

   $h'(0) = 1$, $0 \leqslant h' \leqslant 1$.

It is easy to see that $(\mathscr{T}, \circ)$ is a semigroup, where $\circ$ means function composition. For any $f \in \mathscr{S}$ and $h \in \mathscr{T}$, since$$
(f \circ h)'(x) = f'(h(x)) h'(x) = g(h(x)) h'(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
then $f \circ h \in \mathscr{S}$. Note that for any $x \geqslant 0$,$$
h(x) \leqslant x \Longrightarrow f(h(x)) \leqslant f(x),
$$
thus $f \circ h$ is a sigmoid function the graph of which is below that of $f$.

Comment: can you give me an example of such f that are beneath $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$?

Comment: the most intersting functions are the lower/upper bound functions but it seems really hard to find these

Comment: too bad that these $f_a$ are not defined in the origin, thus do not belong in the set of S-shaped function with slope 1 in the origin and an upper bound of 1. We need a function $f_a$ <= $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ such that  $f_a(0) = 0$ and $f_a'(0) = 1 $. The function needs to converge to the upper bound 1 as well.

Comment: awesome! i was wondering if we have two s_shaped functions $f$ and $g$. Isn't $\frac{f+g}{2}$ also S_shaped? If so one can compute a lot of elements of the set if the upper/lower bound is known.

Comment: thats real neat, i was thinking about an under bound of this set it would help a lot, any ideas?

Comment: BTW, this $f_a$ is also not in the set. Suppose we look only in positive x's, then \$lim_x \rightarrow \infty f_a = \frac{1}{1-a}$

Comment: @KeesTil First, by upper and lower bound do you mean the limits toward $+∞$ and $-∞$, respectively? Second, the definition of the sigmoid function only requires $f$ to be **bounded**, differentiable and increasing. If you mean to require that $f$ has predetermined limits mentioned above, it should be additionally specified in the question.

Comment: ah obviously i am sorry about that, that is not clear indeed i will change it right away

Comment: @KeesTil After the requirement of upper bound added, I found another set of sigmoid functions smaller $f$.

Comment: That an amazing property i think you can use log(1+x) an infinite many times thanks man! You deserve the bounty!

Comment: @KeesTil Thanks. However, it should be pointed out that since the explicit form of $f$ is not known, $h\in\mathscr T$ has to satisfy $h(x)=x$ for $x\leqslant0$. If $f$ is explicitly given, this restriction may be lifted.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to **describe** the set of all such functions. However it is hopeless to try and loop through the set of all such functions or even to describe it with finitely many parameters over which one could try to optimize.

The basic underlying issue is that any such function could be perturbed by a $C^\infty$ function that vanishes to sufficiently high order at the origin and also vanishes at $\pm \infty$. And the set of such perturbations is infinite dimensional in a very strong sense (it contains an ideal of differentiable functions that is not finitely generated).

Comment: I understand, however suppose we have a function $G$ that belongs in this set, Isn't it possible to approximate $G$ very close by dividing the upper and lower bound by $2$ and keep doing this until you are sufficiently close?